# Serving a git repository with nginx fails with 403 Forbidden

Tags: nginx, git, http-status-code-403, fcgi

I made a user `git` and placed an empty bare repository in his home directory `/home/git`:

```
$ git init --bare test.git
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 7 git git 4.0K Jul 18 12:51 test.git
```

I want this repository to be accessible as `example.com/repos/test.git`.

To accomplish this, I have the following `nginx` configuration:

```
location ~ /repos(/.*) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
    fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
    fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/git;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1;
}
```

Attempting to clone the repository fails, however:

```
$ git clone https://example.com/repos/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
remote: 403 Forbidden
fatal: unable to access 'https://example.com/repos/test.git/':
  The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Meanwhile, `nginx` had this to say in its `access.log`:

```
"GET /repos/test/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1"
403 25 "-" "git/2.4.5"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...

After many hours of pulling my hair out, the trick was to reorder the `nginx` configuration.

In addition, to enable pushing, I had to add some `basic-auth` directives.

```
    location ~ /repos(/.*) {
            auth_basic "access denied";
            auth_basic_user_file /path/to/your/htpasswd;
            client_max_body_size 0;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL "";
            fastcgi_param GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /home/git;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $1;
            fastcgi_param REMOTE_USER $remote_user;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
    }
```

For any poor soul perusing this to find an answer to their problem, if after all this you get an "insufficient permission to blah blah" error, fix your repository permissions [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448242/git-push-error-insufficient-permission-for-adding-an-object-to-repository-datab).